# Передача вызова сигнала в обработчик io_service

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Знаю, знаю, сейчас описание будет звучать как извращение, но, к сожалению, очень интересует.

В каком-то из потоков произошло действие, результат которого мне надо обработать в потоке в котором вызван `io_service_.run()`. Причем, код не связный, точнее, связан с помощью библиотеки сигналов `boost::signals2`.

Конкретнее: мне нужно сделать что-то похожее на:

```
io_service_.post(boost::bind(signal_,result_)); //(1)
```

где:
`io_service_` - экземпляр `boost::asio::io_service`,
`signal_` - экземпляр `boost::signals2::signal<void(std::string)>` 
`result_` - параметр типа `std::string`, который хочу передать.

К `signal_` подписан какой-то метод класса, который принимает `std::string`.

Но, к сожалению, строчка (1) не компилируется. Как можно в `boost::bind` передать сигнал с параметром?

Оборачивать вызов сигнала в функцию, передающуюся в `boost::bind` - не хочется.